# MongoDB v3.2.6 Sporadic Slow Queries

Tags: mongodb, database-performance, wiredtiger

Could anyone provide insight on how to troubleshoot the sporadic slowness I'm experiencing w/ mongo, or point out any obvious problems based on my slow operation logs?

I have Mongo v3.2.6 using the WiredTiger engine installed on an m4.large (8GB Ram, 2 virtual cores) ec2 instance running ubuntu server 14.04. There is a java process installed on the same server that reads/writes from/to the mongo process using many threads. There are no replica sets (I know there should be), no memory issues that I can see, however, I've been experiencing sporadical slow queries that I've been unable to diagnose.

The following is the complete log from June 21, 2016 that exhibits some very lengthy queries (10+ seconds), queries that usually complete within a few milliseconds.

```
2016-06-21T01:27:44.806Z I COMMAND  [conn156] update company.token query: { _id: "1111" } update: { _id: "1111", _class: "company.domain.Token", userUUID: "5555", expires: 1466476050734 } keysExamined:1 docsExamined:1 nMatched:1 nModified:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:1 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2, w: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 2 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 2 } } } 14071ms
2016-06-21T01:27:44.806Z I COMMAND  [conn151] update company.token query: { _id: "2222" } update: { _id: "2222", _class: "company.domain.Token", userUUID: "6666", expires: 1466476050414 } keysExamined:1 docsExamined:1 nMatched:1 nModified:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:1 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2, w: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 2 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 2 } } } 14391ms
2016-06-21T01:27:44.811Z I COMMAND  [conn150] insert company.count ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1, w: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } } } 14074ms
2016-06-21T01:39:45.807Z I COMMAND  [conn151] update company.token query: { _id: "3333" } update: { _id: "3333", _class: "company.domain.Token", userUUID: "7777", expires: 1466476776277 } keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 nMatched:1 nModified:1 upsert:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1, w: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } } } 9529ms
2016-06-21T10:34:14.596Z I COMMAND  [conn156] command company.count command: aggregate { aggregate: "count", pipeline: [ { $match: { lId: "4444", $and: [ { iTS: { $gte: 1466475578989 } }, { iTS: { $lte: 1466505254467 } } ] } }, { $group: { _id: { rId: "$rId", sType: "$sType" }, count: { $sum: "$rVal" } } } ] } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:92 reslen:162 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 190 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 95 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 95 } } } protocol:op_query 113ms
2016-06-21T10:39:17.113Z I COMMAND  [conn146] command company.count command: aggregate { aggregate: "count", pipeline: [ { $match: { lId: "4444", $and: [ { iTS: { $gte: 1466475589300 } }, { iTS: { $lte: 1466505556971 } } ] } }, { $group: { _id: { rId: "$rId", sType: "$sType" }, count: { $sum: "$rVal" } } } ] } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:93 reslen:162 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 192 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 96 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 96 } } } protocol:op_query 141ms
2016-06-21T10:41:16.871Z I COMMAND  [conn156] command company.count command: aggregate { aggregate: "count", pipeline: [ { $match: { lId: "4444", $and: [ { iTS: { $gte: 1466475578989 } }, { iTS: { $lte: 1466505676744 } } ] } }, { $group: { _id: { rId: "$rId", sType: "$sType" }, count: { $sum: "$rVal" } } } ] } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:94 reslen:162 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 194 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 97 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 97 } } } protocol:op_query 110ms
```

The slow queries seem to always be `update` or `insert` operations. One collection from the above slow query tables is `company.token`, it has ~55k documents w/ an average size of 160B. This collection is read from very frequently (bursts up to 100x a second about every 15 seconds). The read query is using the primary `_id` key to search, so it's hitting the primary key index.

The other collection from the log is `company.count` which contains ~2.7M documents w/ and average size of 587B and is written to very frequently (bursts of ~100 inserts a second every 15 seconds). The collection has steady aggregate read queries (also shown in the log) executed against collection, dozens per minute. The aggregate read `match` clause hits a compound index and never seems to scan more documents than are returned (`executionStats` shown at bottom). The insert queries tend to finish very fast, about 1-4ms per insert, however, once or twice per day mongo seems to seize up and take 10 sometimes 20 seconds to complete the otherwise fast operations.

My best guess about the lag is from the highly concurrent writes and reads from the two collections from the log, however, I was under the impression that WiredTiger used the intent exclusive and intent shared locks at the document level which should allow high concurrency.

One final note is I sometimes see another collection that contains only a single document take up to 10 seconds to update, so it seems like perhaps the queue of writes and reads is maxed out so to speak at the global or database level. Any way to confirm that?

```
{
  "executionStats":{
    "executionSuccess":true,
    "nReturned":12006,
    "executionTimeMillis":19,
    "totalKeysExamined":12006,
    "totalDocsExamined":12006,
    "executionStages":{
      "stage":"FETCH",
      "nReturned":12006,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate":20,
      "works":12007,
      "advanced":12006,
      "needTime":0,
      "needYield":0,
      "saveState":93,
      "restoreState":93,
      "isEOF":1,
      "invalidates":0,
      "docsExamined":12006,
      "alreadyHasObj":0,
      "inputStage":{
        "stage":"IXSCAN",
        "nReturned":12006,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate":0,
        "works":12007,
        "advanced":12006,
        "needTime":0,
        "needYield":0,
        "saveState":93,
        "restoreState":93,
        "isEOF":1,
        "invalidates":0,
        "keyPattern":{
          "lId":1,
          "iTS":1
        },
        "indexName":"lId_1_iTS_1",
        "isMultiKey":false,
        "isUnique":false,
        "isSparse":false,
        "isPartial":false,
        "indexVersion":1,
        "direction":"forward",
        "indexBounds":{
          "lId":[
            "[\"d4444\", \"4444\"]"
          ],
          "iTS":[
            "[1466475578989.0, 1466505676744.0]"
          ]
        },
        "keysExamined":12006,
        "dupsTested":0,
        "dupsDropped":0,
        "seenInvalidated":0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what could be an issue is index update - that could lock collection for a while...